# How to share redux store in multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hi I have one component in which I integrated the redux in my react application. I am opening second then third component. I don't want the pass the data which I obtained in first component to second then third in props.

I want to do this using redux store. Is there any way to do this ?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import RoundedButton from "./RoundedButton";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      status: "",
      userSelected: "",
      computerSelected: "",
      visibility: [true, true, true],
      buttonVisibility: false
    };
    this.clickitem = this.clickitem.bind(this);
    this.handlePlayAgain = this.handlePlayAgain.bind(this);
  }

  handlePlayAgain() {
    this.setState({
      buttonVisibility: false,
      visibility: [true, true, true]
    });
  }

  clickitem(user) {
    var url = "http://localhost:4000/generate-random";
    this.setState({ userSelected: user });

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        var computer = data.item;
        this.setState({ computerSelected: computer });
        if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock") ||
          (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          this.props.increment();
        } else if (user === computer) {
          this.props.doNothing();
        } else {
          this.props.decrement();
        }

        console.log(user + " " + computer);
        console.log("------------------------------------");

        App.contextTypes = { store: React.PropTypes.object };
        let store = this.context.store;
        console.log(store);

        arrayvar = [];

        var arrayvar = [];
        if (user === "Rock" && computer === "Rock") {
          arrayvar = [true, false, false];
        } else if (user === "Paper" && computer === "Paper") {
          arrayvar = [false, true, false];
        } else if (user === "Scissors" && computer === "Scissors") {
          arrayvar = [false, false, true];
        } else if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Paper") ||
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Rock")
        ) {
          arrayvar = [true, true, false];
        } else if (
          (user === "Rock" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Rock")
        ) {
          arrayvar = [true, false, true];
        } else if (
          (user === "Paper" && computer === "Scissors") ||
          (user === "Scissors" || computer === "Paper")
        ) {
          arrayvar = [false, true, true];
        }
        this.setState({ visibility: arrayvar });
        this.setState({
          buttonVisibility: true
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CenterDiv">
        <div className="AppTitle">
          <b>Score: {this.props.score}</b>
          <div>
            {this.state.visibility[0]
              ? <RoundedButton
                  text="Rock"
                  clickitem={this.clickitem}
                  label={
                    this.state.userSelected === "Rock" &&
                      this.state.computerSelected === "Rock"
                      ? "User & Computer Selected"
                      : this.state.userSelected === "Rock"
                        ? "User Selected"
                        : this.state.computerSelected === "Rock"
                          ? "Computer Selected"
                          : ""
                  }
                />
              : null}
            {this.state.visibility[1]
              ? <RoundedButton
                  text="Paper"
                  clickitem={this.clickitem}
                  label={
                    this.state.userSelected === "Paper" &&
                      this.state.computerSelected === "Paper"
                      ? "User & Computer Selected"
                      : this.state.userSelected == "Paper"
                        ? "User Selected"
                        : this.state.computerSelected === "Paper"
                          ? "Computer Selected"
                          : ""
                  }
                />
              : null}
            {this.state.visibility[2]
              ? <RoundedButton
                  text="Scissors"
                  clickitem={this.clickitem}
                  label={
                    this.state.userSelected === "Scissors" &&
                      this.state.computerSelected === "Scissors"
                      ? "User & Computer Selected"
                      : this.state.userSelected === "Scissors"
                        ? "User Selected"
                        : this.state.computerSelected === "Scissors"
                          ? "Computer Selected"
                          : ""
                  }
                />
              : null}
          </div>

          <div className="Status">{this.props.status}</div>

          {this.state.buttonVisibility
            ? <button onClick={this.handlePlayAgain} style={{ margin: 30 }}>
                Play Again
              </button>
            : null}

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { score: state.score, status: state.status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import "./index.css";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import scoreReducer from "./reducers";

let store = createStore(scoreReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

secondcomponent.js

```
export default class SecondComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       // print score which is in redux
    );
  }
}
```

third component.js

```
export default class ThirdComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       // print score which is in redux
    );
  }
}
```

Whats the way to have an access of redux store in multiple components ?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of `react-redux` tutorials for that.

Comment: [That's not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638314/redux-with-react-right-way-to-share-the-store-with-components)

Comment: You are using an awful lot of `state` in your component. The reason for using Redux and `mapStateToProps` is to use props in your `render`.

Comment: @AlexW so fetch value from store in a different components is not a good practice ?

Comment: I am a bit confused, why don't pass those as props or just make Second and Third Component connected components?

Comment: @Chen I can do that but that is doable using normal state mechanism too, then whats use of redux here ? Afaik redux allows you to share state in different components without sending in props. please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Any** component that is wrapped with `connect`:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AnyComponent);
```

will have access to the **entire** `redux` store.
With `mapStateToProps` you can pass just relevant piece of data from the `redux` store to the connected component via `props`.

About component internal `state`, my rule of thumb is to set internal state just for data that is relevant for the specific component.
For example, `extend` or `collapse` state for a Drop-down.

As for `ajax` requests, if you already using `redux` I highly recommend to use actions with `thunks` or `sagas` and pass the new fetched data through the `redux` flow:
**Action/thunk -> Reducers -> connected components.**

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment,
You don't need to pass every component you want to connect to the Provider, you just pass a root component (`App` in your case) and each child of `App` can connect to `redux` if necessary:

```
class SecondComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       // print score which is in redux
       <div>this.props.score</div> 
    );
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SecondComponent);
```

And as well as for other components:

```
class ThirdComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       // print score which is in redux
       <div>this.props.score</div> 
    );
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ThirdComponent);
```

**Edit #2**
As a followup to your other comment:

> so passing value in props to components or use above said approach,
>   Idk which is recommended ?

Avoid connecting components when you can and pass down the props to the children, the main reason for this is to prevent dependency on `redux`.
I prefer keep my components "dumb" as i can and let them concern only on how things should look.
I do have some components that concern on how things should work and these components are mainly dealing with logic and passing down data to the children, they are the components i often connect.

When i notice that my app is scaling and some of my components are acting as a proxy of props (i even got a word for that! "Propxy"), that is they get props from their parent and pass them down without using them, i usually inject a connected component in the middle of the components tree so i can let the "propxy" components down the tree flow be more lighten and slim.

Comment: What to write here  `<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>,` redux store is accessible those components which are wrapped inside provider. How to set multiple components here ?

Comment: so passing value in props to components or use above said approach, Idk which is recommended ?

Comment: How are you linking the 2nd and 3rd component to the same store. What if I have many stores?

Answer (score 2):

The generic approach of using `redux` in react applications is use it along with `react-redux` library. That library provides `connect` function, which helps to access store in react components in more clean way.

Instead of trying to access store via context, just use `connect` function:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const SecondComponent = ({ score }) => <div>{score}</div>

// with help of `connect`, you are providing `score` prop to `SomeComponent`
// next, you can render that connected component anywhere in your app
export default connect(
  (state) => ({
    score: state.score
  })
)(SecondComponent)
```

You could use connect for any of your react components such as `ThirdComponent` ad so on.

Comment: `const SecondComponent = ({ score }) => <div>{score}</div>` Shouldn't it `this.props.score` here like `const SecondComponent = ({ score }) => <div>{this.props.score}</div>`

Comment: @Williams no, it's stateless functional component - https://www.jstwister.com/post/react-stateless-functional-components-best-practices/

You should use this.props.score only when you are using class components