# Connecting child components to store vs connecting parent component to store and passing down props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

After a lot of search and working with React and React Native. I still have a pretty vague opinion on which
is best to use and in what situations

1. Having the parent component be connected to the store and passing as props all data to children functional components. This what I initial though was the "React" way but pretty soon I saw that as the app grow the amount of logic handled by this parent component starting too be to big and messy.Also child components start to have children of its own and so on and so forth.
2. Having parent component (`Screen` for example) that is functional and each child that needs information from the store will be connected to it. This is much more "clean" solution but will create a lot of store connection "duplications" which are not necessary.

Using Redux store

My question in general which is more recommended pattern to use and in which use cases, also would be nice to know what is the price for having a lot of connected (containers) components

Comment: 2nd one is more recommended, with Redux as debugging with Redux devtools for Chrome is easy. Common props in child components should be extracted to a global store/state. If you have a lot of connected components, update to 1 variable in the store will cause re-renders/updates in all components, thus lagging. You need to then either disintegrate your stores more(preferred), or use shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: Thank you, this reenforce my thoughts exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure i can provide a right or wrong answer for this question as each has its pros and cons.
My rule of thumb is to connect deeply nested components only when their parents are "proxies of props". That is they accepts props only to pass them down to their children.

If i may quote (myself) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797695/3148807):

> Avoid connecting components when you can and pass down the props to
>   the children, the main reason for this is to prevent dependency on
>   redux. I prefer keep my components "dumb" as i can and let them
>   concern only on how things should look. I do have some components that
>   concern on how things should work and these components are mainly
>   dealing with logic and passing down data to the children, they are the
>   components i often connect.
>
> When i notice that my app is scaling and some of my components are
>   acting as a proxy of props (i even got a word for that! "Propxy"),
>   that is they get props from their parent and pass them down without
>   using them, i usually inject a connected component in the middle of
>   the components tree so i can let the "propxy" components down the tree
>   flow be more lighten and slim

You should also note that one more pitfall with connected components is that each render will trigger the `mapstateToProps` method. if you got some heavy logic there you should memoize it, usually done with [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)

As for the benefit of connecting a component, well you probably realize that already. you get quick access to the `Provider`'s state via react's context.

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> about the rendering - wont I have much more unnecessary rendering if Ill have a deep nested children (common in medium to large apps) that will be unnecessarily re rendered on each parent update

Well the `connect` HOC wrapper won't trigger a re-render if the previous object of `mapStateToProps` is the same as the current object returned. so no unnecessary re-renders to your connected component will take place.
You can read in more details on how it works and how the logic was evolved over time in [this article](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2018/11/react-redux-history-implementation/)

Comment: to be honest I had 0 use cases when I had to put logic inside `mapStateToProps`. It always returns an object and thats it. about the rendering - wont I have much more unnecessary rendering if Ill have a deep nested children (common in medium to large apps) that will be unnecessarily re rendered on each parent update?

Answer (score 0):

I use the first option.
The cons you wrote are correct, but i think its easier to debug and understand the data flow this way.

Comment: actually if you use `redux-logger` its easier to debug the second option. From my experience at least

Answer (score 0):

- Don't connect a component to redux if the current component doesn't use this data from redux and only passes.
- If the component uses data then connect to redux.
- If the current component uses data from redux and the next component also uses it then you can pass and don't need to connect the next component to redux.

**MAIN RULE:**
if there is a gap in the data usage chain from parent to child then don't need to pass data from parent to child

connect(parent) (don't use props) => child (don't use) => child (don't use) => child (using) - better to connect last child. Isuue related to props dreeling